# Concat string to field in multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, studio3t

I have several collections within the same database: `assessments_1`, `assessments_2`, `assessments_3`, `assessments_4` ect
Each of the collections has an existing fields titled `"test_name"` and `"vendor"`.
When `vendor` = `"Bridge"` and `test_name` = `"Tabulation"`, I would like to concat `"EM - "` to the beginning of the `test_name` field so it becomes `"EM - Tabulation"`.

I've looked though the [mongoDB manual](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) on `concat`, but there are no references to update across collections.

I'm on MongoDB 4.4.4. Using Studio3T.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The update itself is trivial. You just need to repeat it once per collection.

Comment: I am in the process of updating each of the 45 collections manually. There are actually 15 test names to concat the "EM -" to. I simplified the details for the question. If I could list the collections and then cycle through each of the fields, that would save me quite a bit of work. I figure I can also just use something like this: { $or : [ { "test_name" : "Tabulation" }, { "test_name" : "Timing" } ], "vendor" : "Bridge" }

Comment: Rather than `"$or"`, you could use `"test_name": {"$in": ["Tabulation", "Timing", ...]}`.

Comment: The scenario seems weird to me. If the documents in these collections share similar schemas, you should consider putting them in the same collection instead of putting them in many similar collections with similar naming